# dpkg: error processing package liblmdb0:amd64

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing package liblmdb0:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Setting up libevdocument3-4:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libevview3-3:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up evince-common (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up evince (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libepoxy0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 liblmdb0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting this error every time I execute these commands on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04
I can't uninstall programs in my system and I'm also getting a System Error popup everytime my computer starts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to fully reinstall this package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall liblmdb0
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below commands to get rid of `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

```
sudo apt --purge remove liblmdb0:amd64
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I doubt that will work in this situation. Have you tested it?